# How to open fpdf report by button click

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a button to open a fpdf report named **report.php**. My code as follows. 
The button enable disable according to a flag.

Please help me with this.

```
    <?php $i = 0;
        for($data AS $value){ ?>

<td>
<?php echo $value['flag'];
if($value['flag'] == 1 ){ ?>
    <input type="button" style="width: 70px" value="open" onclick="">
<?php } else{ ?>
    <input type="button" style="width: 70px" value="open" onclick="" disabled>
<?php }?>
  <input type="hidden" id="flag<?php echo $i?>" value="<?php echo $value['flag'] ?>">
</td
<?php $i++;
        } ?>
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $value['flag'];
if($value['flag'] == 1 ){ ?>
    <input type="button" style="width: 70px" value="open" onclick="window.location.href='report.php';">
<?php } else{ ?>
    <input type="button" style="width: 70px" value="open" onclick="return false;" disabled>
<?php }?>
  <input type="hidden" id="flag<?php echo $i?>" value="<?php echo $value['flag'] ?>">
</td
<?php $i++;
        } ?>
```